# JavaScript - Discord.JS | How to check if a variable is the same as a string

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to find out a way to check if a string is the same as a variable.
**For example:**

```
const config = require("./config.json");
const amount1 = config.amount1;
const amount2 = config.amount2;
// How would I check if amount1 and amount2 are the same as the variable "invite.code"
```

If this was the case, I would like to set another variable as shown,

```
var amount = ?;
```

If amount1 was invite.code, I would like amount to be amount1.
I've tried google and nothing has helped or shown me anything.

Comment: You might want to try reading an introduction to Javascript tutorial. It will cover "conditionals" (if/else statements) and a lot of other things that you'll likely have questions about when you're first starting out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good work with the `const` usage. Stay with it. Here is how you do it using `const`.

```
const amount1 = config.amount1;
const amount2 = config.amount2;

const amount = amount1 === invite.code ? amount1 : amount2
```

It's a [ternary condition assignment](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-ternary-operator/).

The general form is:

```
const const_name = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Comment: The ternary operator might be a bit advanced, considering the OP doesn't know what an if/else statement is.

Comment: And if he never learns it, that will be good. Because then he won't be seduced into using `var` for constant values.... because if you use if/else here, you are forced to falsely make a constant value a mutable `var`, unless you wrap the if behind the singularity of a function.